# What is the Java equivalent to webmin?

Tags: java, linux, apache, configuration, frameworks

[webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) is a administration/UI framework for configuring software. I am curious if anyone know what the Java equivalent might be?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you looking for something to configure Java or for something like webmin written in Java?

Comment: Something like webmin written in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since there is no "java operating system" it will be hard to find an exact equivalent.

a good tool for inspecting and configuring a *single JVM* is the JMX protocol and its clients [visualvm](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) and the [Jconsole](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html)

Answer (score 1):

Webmin looks to be by definition absolutely platform dependant (at least to Unix systems). A Java equivalent would make no sense - sure, you could write such a tool in Java, but it would not be portable and probably require significant amounts of non-Java code to access platform specific APIs

Answer (score 0):

webmin is written in perl, which, while available on many more platforms than Java, in reality isn't much more portable.  And almost all of it is based on managing text files and known Unix commands, all which would be doable from Java.

I've been thinking long and hard about starting a project like this - the microsoft world has a number of tools that makes managing clusters of systems easy, but not so the Unix world.  cfengine is nice, but clumsy.  I want webmin that can manage my entire network from one console.  I've thought something integrated with OpenNMS would be a nice place to start.

But the short answer is that there is no Java version of webmin.